# Using a Raspberry pi, mic works perfectly fine for everything, except for code (r.listen(source))

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, pip, speech-recognition

I'm working on a speech to morse code Group Project.  The problem is that the raspberry pi has a problem of using the USB mic in the listen() function of the program.

It works completely fine on laptops, but it doesn't on an RPi for some reason.  The mics work completely fine everywhere else, using arecord -d, and testing on discord.  I installed a majority of the stuff required using pip install: Pyaduio, speech recognition, and portaudio, at least all the stuff I needed for the laptops.  I am using Python 2.7.13, and I've tried it on Python 3; same issue.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak Anything :")
    audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said : {}".format(text))
    except:
        print("Sorry could not recognize what you said")
```

The expected result is supposed to print what you said; however, what it would do is either get stuck on "Speak Anything:" or "Sorry could not recognize what you said."

I really need some help with this.  Out of everything to do on this project, I've spent the most time on this, which seems to be something that is supposed to be easy.

Comment: May be worth trying to run your code using `sudo` in case it is a permissions issue.

Comment: You shouldn't use bare `except:` because it masks the exception. Please remove it or print the error and the traceback inside exception handler. Show the traceback.